# Php anonymous function with short array not work in 5.4.35

Tags: php

I have an odd issue with this php script

```
<?php

$expr = '["Nizky_tarif","Vysoky_tarif"][0 == 1]';
$newfunc = @create_function('', "return $expr;");

var_dump($newfunc);
echo $newfunc();
```

On server it crashes with error:

```
bool(false)
PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in /tmp/foo.php on line 7
```

On localhost it works:

```
string(9) "\000lambda_1"
Nizky_tarif
```

Server php version is 5.4.35, localhost 5.6.3. However I don't see why it wouldn't work, the short array syntax was added in 5.4, right?

ps. Just tried, if I change it to the old array syntax, it crashes also.

Comment: I didn't believe `create_function` was a real function until I just looked it up.  Surely there is a better way to do whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: I think so too, this is some legacy code. I believe the intent is to eval it safely in separate scope or sth like that.

Comment: @MightyPork maybe the hoster has disactivated in some way anonymous function? Oo

Comment: doubt that, it works for other simpler things like "1 == 1". Also, I have root access to the server, if you have ideas I can try.

Comment: what does the script need to do? syntax isn't really the issue here, we can use a different syntax.

Comment: [array and string literal dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.const-dereferencing) was introduced in 5.5 - it won't work with 5.4. So `["a", "b"][0]` is not valid 5.4 code.

Comment: @vstm Oh, that's a bummer. Alright, this is the real issue here, I just tested it. If you write it as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression `["Nizky_tarif","Vysoky_tarif"][0 == 1]` the code is trying to directly dereference an array literal. This is a [feature which was introduced with PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.const-dereferencing).

With PHP 5.4 this expression is not valid, resulting in the error "Function name must be a string".

You could change that into to parts to make it work:

```
$data = ["Nizky_tarif","Vysoky_tarif"];
return $data[0 == 1];
```